# Difficulty to run simple GWT application

Tags: gwt

I am making gwt application as following step:

1. Firstly I install gwt plugin in my eclipse(Helios).
2. Create dynamic project.
3. Add gwt plugin through

   1. going to property page of the project
   2. Select google-webtoolkit
   3. check "use GWT"
   4. then go to google-web application
   5. the directory name to "web-content".
4. Create gwt module in my project then create entry point class then html.
5. Create a button in onModule method of entry point class.

Then I run the application in tomcat server by just right clicking on project and selecting run as web application(run with tomcat server). As result of this I am getting a blank page on browser? There is no excption in server log. I am not able to debug. Where I am going wrong?
Please help me to sort out this problem.

I am not using google web application because I was getting difficulty to create war file. As a result of this I got the above process to develop GWT application.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try in reverse:

1. First install gwt plugin in my eclipse(Helios).
2. Create GWT project
3. Add Dynamic web plugin

   1. going to property page of the project
   2. project Facets tab
   3. Select Dynamic Web Module and java
   4. ok to apply changes.
4. Write your code

and try to run on server. it will work.

Comment: yes,i am creating gwt application as you suggest steps.After completing all 4 steps when i am trying to run on server than it showing an error that the server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification.how can we change version to another. so please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: put your dynamic web plugin 2.5 version and java 1.6 version

Comment: go to property page -> project facet tab than change dynamic wen plugin version